# Parsing text from webpage using htmlagility

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

Trying to scrape a text from a web page with little result so far. I am trying to use HtmlAgility for this.

The source from the webpage looks like this

```html
<div class="state info">
        <h4 class="member-states parse"><span class="trim">Nebraska NE</span></h3>
```

I just want to retrieve the text "Nebraska NE" and leave everything else from the webpage out. Is there a simple way to go about this?

Comment: just curious - why not use the web browser control (if you are using a winforms app) and find the element and finally extract the text?

Comment: how you are doing this  with htmlagilitypack please post a sample code

Comment: Why not use BS4? just my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

here a sample  on  how  you  can get  this

```
  HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter xmlTxtWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.ASCII);            
       htmlWeb.LoadHtmlAsXml(uriofhtmlPageToload, xmlTxtWriter);
        ms.Position = 0;
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(ms);
        XElement xHtml = xdoc.Root;
        string nameSpace = "{" + xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().ToString() + "}";
        XElement xBody = xHtml.Element(nameSpace + "body");
        List<XElement> xBodyElts = xBody.Descendants().ToList();
        string elt = string.Empty;
        foreach (var eltPage in xBodyElts)
        {
            if (eltPage.Name == nameSpace + "div")
            {
                if (eltPage.Attribute("class") != null && eltPage.Attribute("class").Value == "page")
                {

                    foreach (XElement eltBlockh4 in eltPage.Descendants(nameSpace + "h4"))
                    {
                        foreach (XElement eltBlockspan in eltBlockh4.Descendants(nameSpace + "span"))
                        {
                            if (eltBlockspan.Attribute("class") != null && eltBlockspan.Attribute("class").Value == "trim")
                            {
                                elt = eltBlockspan.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank's for the reply, trying to use the code but getting this error when I put in the url in the line 
'htmlWeb.LoadHtmlAsXml(uriofhtmlPageToload, xmlTxtWriter);' ->

_
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.LoadHtmlAsXml(string, System.Xml.XmlTextWriter)'

Comment: code updated HtmlWeb object was missing  let us know if this resolve your issue

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much for you help, saved my a bunch of time researching, have a nice one and take care

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("path/to/html");
 //select each span which class contains 'trim'
 foreach(HtmlNode span in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class,'trim')]")
 {
    //add the Text by assigning it using 'span.InnerText'
 }
```

If this text only appears once you can simple assign it to a string, if it appears more then once store it in a collection like a `List<string>`

Answer (score 1):

Using Beautiful soup, very easy to traverse through the code.

Here is a simple code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="state info"> <h4 class="member-states parse"><span class="trim">Nebraska NE</span></h3>')
print soup.text
```

Prints

```
 Nebraska NE
```

It is just my suggestion if you are seeking any other way to web scraping.